# How to connect RoamResearch to Zapier?

Tags: zapier, roamresearch

Is there any way to connect a RoamResearch graph:

- from Twitter (e.g. when I like some tweet, it goes directly inside RoamResearch)
- to a blog post (e.g. when I tag a block with #ok-to-publish everything that is beneath is used and sent as a blog post on Blogger or Wordpress)
- from Slack (e.g. when I favorite a Slack message it goes directly on my Roam today page)

It would be awesome this automation could be setup through a no-code platform like Zapier (for low maintenance on my side).

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, since no solution was out there, I made **[Roam-bot](https://roam-bot.com/)** to automate everything (read and write) in and out of RoamResearch through Zapier!

- It's low maintenance, I only need to maintain my Zapier workflows
- Always works
- Faster than self-hosted alternatives

[image: RoamResearch to Zapier]